# Send DM when a user joins a VC using Discord.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Stack Overflow (I apologize if this question has already been asked, I don't believe it has, but in advance, just in case):

I'm making a discord bot using Discord.JS and Node.JS. I want to make a bot to detect when a user joins a VC, and then sends said user a DM. I have the detection code figured out:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.login("token");

bot.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log(`Bot ready, logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
})

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID;
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;
 
    if(newUserChannel === "channel id")
    { 
        // User Joins a voice channel
        console.log("User joined vc with id "+newUserChannel)
        
    }
    else{
        // User leaves a voice channel
        console.log("Left vc");
    }
 });
```

But I'm having trouble sending the user (who i assume is represented by newMember) a DM. Can someone kindly provide some assistance? Thanks!

Comment: What do you need help with? Please specify it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=member) property of the [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) instance you get to get the user who has joined the voice channel. Then simply call the [`.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send) method on the voice channel user to send them a DM. Take a look at the example code below:

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  const newChannelID = newState.channelID;

  if (newChannelID === "channel id") {
    console.log("User has joined voice channel with id " + newChannelID);

    const member = newState.member;

    member.send('Hi there! Welcome to the voice channel!');
  } else {
    console.log("User left or didn't join the channel matching the given ID");
  }
});
```

Give it a try and see how it goes